# PHP & XML: How to remove all whitespaces outside "terminal elements"

Tags: php, xml

First let's define "terminal element" (for the particular purpose of this question).

By "terminal element" I mean the *elements* that contain no other *elements* inside.

*Element* reference: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

How to remove from a XML document/node all whitespaces (line feeds, carriage returns, tabs and spaces) that are outside "terminal elements" with PHP?

Rules: Only PHP native XML parsers (no regex).

Comment: Another word for "terminal elements" could be *leaf-nodes* that are  *element-nodes*. What you perhaps aim for is to remove *significant whitespace* text-nodes. As most of PHP's XML libraries are based on libxml, the [`LIBXML_NOBLANKS` constant](http://php.net/libxml.constants.php) might be what you're looking for, document normalization (as suggested 2 days ago) or [`DOMDocument::$preserveWhitespace`](http://php.net/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace).

Comment: Yes i want to remove all significant whitespaces from a document, not precisely normalize documents or nodes, just erase whitespaces. Has nothing to do with "valid" or "normal", since those whitespaces does count when you sign a document, it is valid/normal data, but i want to remove it anyways (only the ones outside "terminal elements").

Comment: DOMDocument::load / loadXML with LIBXML_NOBLANKS was very close, but it did not remove all whitespaces outside "terminal elements", and it removed some inside. It transforms whitespaces sequences into single spacebars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All whitespace outside "terminal elements" (leaf element nodes) is within text-nodes (as all text is within text-nodes). So if you get all text-nodes that are outside of terminal elements, you can remove all whitespace-characters from those. This is the answer already.

Let's start lightly by just removing whitespace from one text-node in an XML Document.

As PHP uses UTF-8 as character encoding for the XML parsers (I use [**DOMDocument**](http://php.net/DOMDocument) in this example), [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) is handy here as it knows both UTF-8 and what whitespace characters are:

```
/** @var DomText $text */
$text->nodeValue = preg_replace('~\s+~u', '', $text->textContent);
```

This removes all whitespace from a text-node. Here is a demonstration of that:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<root> Very Simple Demo </root>');

$text = $doc->documentElement->childNodes->item(0);

/** @var DomText $text */
$text->nodeValue = preg_replace('~\s+~u', '', $text->textContent);

$doc->save('php://output');
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>VerySimpleDemo</root>
```

As you can see the space characters are removed from the one and only text-node that is part of that document.

With a larger document and your "terminal elements", this is naturally more interesting, but works pretty much the same. The only difference is to get all text-node that are not part of leaf-element-nodes. This is best done with an xpath query:

```
//*[*]/text()
```

This reads: All text-nodes that are children of element that contain other elements. Let's use the following XML (file `content.xml`) as an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<content>
    <parent>
        <child id="1">
            <title>child 1</title>

            <child id="1">
                <title>
                    child 1.1 with whitespace
                </title>
            </child>
        </child>
    </parent>
</content>
```

It contains both such leaf-elements as well as other elements that have child-elements. It also shows pretty well the whitespace as it's used for element indentation.

After loading it:

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/content.xml';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($file);
```

A [**DOMXPath**](http://php.net/DOMXPath) is necessary to execute the xpath-query:

```
$xp    = new DOMXPath($doc);
$texts = $xp->query('//*[*]/text()');
```

What's left is to iterate over all those text-nodes and apply the whitespace removal as above:

```
foreach ($texts as $text) {
    /** @var DomText $text */
    $text->nodeValue = preg_replace('~\s+~u', '', $text->textContent);
}
```

The result then is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<content><parent><child id="1"><title>child 1</title><child id="1"><title>
                    child 1.1 with whitespace
                </title></child></child></parent></content>
```

This should answer the question. But it wouldn't be XML if there wouldn't be a little bit more verbosity or a little kind of *"but..."*.

Note that "`text()`" in xpath represents all kind of text-nodes incl. CDATA sections. If a CDATA section contains of whitespace only, the code above renders an empty CDATA section ("`<![CDATA[]]>`") into the output. One way to deal with that is to remove the the empty nodes from the document:

```
/** @var DomText $text */
$text->nodeValue = preg_replace('~\s+~u', '', $text->textContent);
if (!$text->length) {
    $text->parentNode->removeChild($text);
}
```

This then removes *all* emptied text-nodes form the document then. Keeping the document tree tidy. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[DOMDocument::normalizeDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.normalizedocument.php) may do what you're looking for.

If you want to normalize individual elements, you can call [DOMNode::normalize](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.normalize.php)

Comment: (Link-only posts are better positioned as comments under the question; if anywhere on the page.  Links can break/die which would render an answer useless.)